# getting isse about how to add select2 extension to yii

Tags: yii2

getting an error cant upload the extension kartik select2....

need some ideaaa
using yii  want to install the select 2 extension in the branch table...

```
<div class="branches-form">

 <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>
<?=$form->field($model,'companies_company_id')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
    'data' =>ArrayHelper::map(Companies::find()->all(),'company_id','company_name'),['prompt'=>'Select Company'] ,
    'language' => 'en',
    'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Select a state ...'],
    'pluginOptions'=> [
        'allowClear' => true
    ],
]); ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'branch_name')->textInput(['maxlength' => 100]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'branch_address')->textInput(['maxlength' => 255]) ?>


    <?= $form->field($model, 'branch_status')->dropDownList([ 'active' => 'Active', 'inactive' => 'Inactive', '' => '', ], ['prompt' => 'Status']) ?>

    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Update', ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
    </div>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

</div>
```

Comment: And the error is ?...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Properly read this documentation http://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/select2

Try this solution:

Also include `use kartik\select2\Select2;` at the top of your file.

```
<?= Select2::widget([
'attribute' => 'companies_company_id',
'model' => $model,
    'data' =>ArrayHelper::map(Companies::find()->all(),'company_id','company_name'),['prompt'=>'Select Company'] ,
    'language' => 'en',
    'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Select a state ...'],
    'pluginOptions'=> [
        'allowClear' => true
    ],
]) ?>
```